# Angular JS upload and download for all formats

Tags: sql, angularjs

Technologies used:
Frontend: Angular JS
Backend: SQL

We need to upload all formats of files into SQL DB by using Angular JS and need to download the uploaded files. Here by using some methods we are converting the uploaded file into "Blob" Format and stored in SQL.

After insertion into SQL we are trying to download the file in same format. But here we are able to download only text format files by using "ng-filesaver" concept. But remaining file format are not able to download. So which concept we need to use to download any format of files by using AngularJS. Please help us we are working from last 15 days on this.

Comment: what you have done so far? code please

Comment: Are you aware that "other file formats" might include non-textual contents? How do you transfer those files from your application towards the server and back?

Comment: ignore above coment
@FDavidov: The file formats may be all image formats, .pdf, .xls, .odc, etc.,

Hi pro.mean: Please find below code. 
Format 1:
HTML: '<a href="{{fileUrl}}" class="col-md-6" download="{{reg.file_name}}">{{reg.file_name}}</a>'

Controller:
' 
if($scope.reg.file_name.indexOf('jpg')> 0){
$scope.ext = "jpg";
var blobFile = $scope.reg.file_upload;
blobFile = blobFile.toString();
blobFile = blobFile.split(',');
var data =atob(blobFile[1]);
blob = new Blob([data], { type: 'image/jpeg' }),
$scope.fileUrl = window.navigator.msSaveBlob(blob, $scope.reg.file_name);
}'